# Eclipse Java Stream Cast Issue

Tags: java, java-8

All,

I have the following lines of code.

```
List<String> nodeList = Stream.of(nodes.split(","))
      .map(String::trim)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

this compiles using gradle. But when it runs, it gives the following exception.

```
Unresolved compilation problem:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<String>
```

I'm not sure what else to provide, ask and I will respond.

Comment: You seem to have a variable naming problem, where `nodes` is defined in terms of itself. Presumably there's actually another variable.

Comment: what is `nodes` in the `Stream.of(nodes.split(","))`?

Comment: this is 99.99% an Eclipse issue, try `javac`

Comment: @LouisWasserman Sorry, I updated it. It has a different name in the source.

Comment: @YCF_L A `string`

Comment: what Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: @Eugene I'm able to compile with gradle outside of Eclipse. I'm using 4.7.3

Comment: then I will repeat myself, `javac` works? If yes, Eclipse issue - report it. And I am sure gradle calls `javac` and not Eclipse `ECJ` which `!= javac`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176281/discussion-between-screenmutt-and-eugene).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting compile time error because there is a mismatch in **compiler version** in project properties. May be you selected **lower version** then the **feature exist in version(1.8)**.

**You need to check and make sure for below:**

Go to project properties

1. Make sure appropriate **JDK** has been selected in Java Build Path. e.g. **JDK 1.8** in this case.
2. Make sure appropriate  compiler version must be selected under **Java Compiler** in project properties. e.g. 1.8

**Or** you can directly add `compileOptions` in your gradle file

```
compileOptions 
{  
     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8  
     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8  
}
```

Comment: If it were a version problem, then ecj would answer: "Method references are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above". OTOH, I could not find a version of ecj that raises the shown compile error when invoked with -1.8. <shrug>

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on my machine which is using JDK8 to compile it.  Try to add the compileOption to your gradle to make sure you are using jdk8 or above like :

```
compileOptions {  
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8  
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, everyone.

I had added the following lines to gradle in order to enable clover support.

```
eclipse.project {
   natures "org.openclover.eclipse.core.clovernature"

   buildCommands.clear()
   buildCommand "org.openclover.eclipse.core.prejavabuilder"
   buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
   buildCommand "org.openclover.eclipse.core.postjavabuilder"
}
```

Removing them fixed the problem.